# Evaluating $\int ^\frac{\pi}{2}_{0} \sin\left(2x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the exact value of the following definite integral: 
>   $$\int ^\frac{\pi}{2}_{0} \sin\left(2x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\:dx=\left[-\frac{1}{2}(2x+\frac{\pi}{4})\right]^\frac{\pi}{2}_{0}$$ 
>   $$=-\frac{1}{2}\left(2\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(2\cdot 0+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
>   $$=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

but the right answer is:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin{\left(2x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\:dx}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Help me out! thanks!

Comment: hint: where is the $\cos$ after integration?

Comment: oh!....so sorry! my fault!!!!i didn't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forget $\cos$ after you have done antiderivative.
Solve-

> $$\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_{0}\sin\left(2x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\:dx=\left[-\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right]^\frac{\pi}{2}_{0}$$
>   $$=-\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2\cdot 0+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
>   $$=-\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \quad \blacksquare$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(2x+\tfrac{\pi}{4})\,dx=[−\tfrac{1}{2}\cos(2x+\tfrac{π}{4})]_0^{\pi/2}=2\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/161783) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.